# Is there any way to cross-reference fixest::etable()?

Tags: r, bookdown, cross-reference, fixest

## Question

Is there any way to cross reference `fixest::etable()`?
I know `etable` is a simple method, but it's actually very useful.
If there is a way to do this, it would be very helpful.

The environment is Windows 10, using R 4.1.2 and running `bookdown::render_book()` in RStudio.
The following is the file structure and the contents of each file.

- index.Rmd
- _bookdown.yml
- _output.yml

## Source code

index.Rmd

````
---
title: "test"
author: "null"
output: pdf_document
fontfamily: lmodern
documentclass: bxjsarticle
classoption: |
  xelatex,
  ja=standard,
  a4
link-citations: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE,
    message = FALSE,
    dev = "cairo_pdf",
    results = "asis"
)
```

```{r model}
library(fixest)
model <- feols(dist ~ speed, cars)
```

```{r etable}
etable(model, title = "etable", tex = TRUE)
```

\@ref(tab:etable)
````

_bookdown.yml

```yaml
delete_merged_file: true
```

_output.yml

```yaml
bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    dev: cairo_pdf
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: true
```

## Results

As shown in the figure, the cross reference will be "??".
For now, I have to number them by hand without using cross references.

[image: output image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`etable` has a `label` argument:

```
library(fixest)
model = feols(dist ~ speed, cars)
etable(model, label = "tab:etable", tex = TRUE)

#> \begin{table}[htbp]
#>    \caption{\label{tab:etable} no title}
#>    \centering
#>    \begin{tabular}{lc}
#>       \tabularnewline \midrule \midrule
#>       Dependent Variable: & dist\\  
#>       Model:              & (1)\\  
#>       \midrule
#>       \emph{Variables}\\
#>       (Intercept)         & -17.58$^{**}$\\   
#>                           & (6.758)\\   
#>       speed               & 3.932$^{***}$\\   
#>                           & (0.4155)\\   
#>       \midrule
#>       \emph{Fit statistics}\\
#>       Observations        & 50\\  
#>       R$^2$               & 0.65108\\  
#>       Adjusted R$^2$      & 0.64381\\  
#>       \midrule \midrule
#>       \multicolumn{2}{l}{\emph{IID standard-errors in parentheses}}\\
#>       \multicolumn{2}{l}{\emph{Signif. Codes: ***: 0.01, **: 0.05, *: 0.1}}\\
#>    \end{tabular}
#> \end{table}
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: I have no idea why I missed the `label` argument. Anyway, @laurent-bergé is more correct.

**NOTE**: This answer is translated from [my original post](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/85344/fixestetable%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b9%e3%83%aa%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%83%ac%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%82%92%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95%e3%81%af%e3%81%82%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b) (in Japanese).

I guess **fixest** package have no options for the cross references on Rmd. Although it may be a kind of kludge, I found that you can insert LaTeX command in the `title` argument like the following.

````
```{r etable}
etable(model, title = "\\label{tab:etable}etable", tex = TRUE)
```
````

Addendum: In general, bookdown doesn't support to refer to the tables by the chunk labels, only to plots. Other packages (e.g. **officedown**) can refer to the table by the chunk labels.

You can also use **stargazer** pacakge to tabulate the result of regression analysis easily, but you may need some tricks too (see https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/175).